# Actions on key pressing, one after the other. (Jquery : RPG Dialogue Box)

Tags: jquery, text, dialog

I'm trying to make a little game in Jquery, I want to show a dialogue box.

1. When I press enter, I want the text1 to appear.
2. I press enter again it shows the text2 etc, until maybe 7 texts.

If I press enter, I get immediatly text2, which is obvious, and I dont know how to figure this out.

Also if you have suggestions of a better optimised solution in Jquery, feel free to submit it, I'm a new student.

Thanks all !

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 && i == 0) {
     $( ".text" ).empty();
        $( ".text" ).append( "Text1" );
        i++;
    }
});
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 && i == 1) {
     $( ".text" ).empty();
        $( ".text" ).append( "Text2" );
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: You added a `keypress event callback` twice. Only add the `keypress event callback` once and use your logic of the value of i to populate the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the keypress event multiple times, use your variable i logic inside the event callback function like so:

Also, if you are just going to clear the text on each evaluation of i, you can just use `.text()` to set the elements text instead of clearing it and appending...

```
var i = 0;
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        switch(i){
            case 0:
               $( ".text" ).empty();
               $( ".text" ).append( "Text1" );

               //Could do it in one line like:
               //$(".text" ).text("Text1");
               break;
           case 1:
               $( ".text" ).empty();
               $( ".text" ).append( "Text2" );
               break;
           etc....
        }

        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Just, on the first press it doesnt work, I had to start by case 0. Thanks a lot

Comment: @HugoNicaise I'm glad I could help. Have a good day. Also, I updated my answer to reflect starting with 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might get you closer. Create an array of the text messages you want to display (var text). Then on enter key press iterate through the messages until you run out. Check if you've ran out by using the ol' typeof !== 'undefined' trick.

There's probably a more elegant answer but I think this one is fairly straight forward and easy to understand.

```
<div class="text></div>

<script>
    var i = 0;
    var text = ['text1','text2','text3'];
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13 && typeof(text[i]) !== 'undefined') {
            $( ".text" ).append( '<p>' + text[i] + '</p>' );
            i++;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I will try it ! Thanks for your time Joe